# Как правильно склоняется фамилия Донос?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно склоняется фамилия Донос?

Answer (score 1):

Женская не изменяется по падежам, мужская - как обычное слово мужского рода на согласный: Донос, Доноса, Доносу, о Доносе.
Вот сама по себе фамилия, конечно, любопытная. Она русская?

Comment: Возможно имеет отношение к "Донат" (переход т в конце в с, и одного а в о) ?